# Background not appearing in div

Tags: html, image, background-image

I'm trying to add a banner image and adjust its size from the CSS. The IMAGE and the CSS are in the same folder, next to each another.

HTML

```
<body>
<header>

    <div class="banner"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.banner {
background: url("games_header.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
background-size: contain;
display: block;
margin: auto;
max-width: 100%;
height: 25%;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You have no content in that element, therefore its height is 0 => no visible background. Just add some content and the background will appear.

The `height` setting has no effect if the parent element doesn't have a set height. If you want the banner to be 25% of the window height, add this rule:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I added some text to the div and the text appeared, but no background.

Comment: .banner {
 background-image: url("games_header.jpg");
 display: block;
 height: 100%; 
}

   <div class="banner">
  Hello
  </div>

Comment: Looking again at your HTML: Also the `header` element needs some height setting if it doesn't contain anything else than the `banner` DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I put it all in the html file I created and this works for my image that's in the same directory. You don't need to call it as div.banner, adding the class to the div is enough to just call it by what you name it.

```
    <head>

    <style>
        .banner{
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('./butterbot.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="banner"></div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`background` is an inline attribute and would work with root elements such as `html` or `body` attributes if you set the background styling to `<body>`(just an example). Though it is not advised to use it on the `html` and `body` but a fixed position div with 100% width and height as shown below

```css
.banner {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/200") no-repeat fixed center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```